# add 2 more attribute values to the magento order view page section

Tags: magento, attributes, admin

in the magento admin panel, if we go for Orders section

and if we click on one order, we can see the Product name and sku at the bottom.

i want to add 2 more attributes to the order section.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name and Sku attributes are added in the file app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\items\column\name.phtml
So you need to make changes there to add any other product attribute.

Comment: hi,

please help me what code changes i have to do display 2 more attributes in order view page.